# Converting Apache WP to Nginx with WURFL

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, wurfl

I'm having some issues trying to convert a project that runs on apache over to nginx. The rest of my set up seems to be fine, because the index.php is running, but errors out when it hits the WURFL directory, which I'll display in a minute.

Does anyone have any experience doing this? I couldn't find any similar examples on SO, or through regular google search that were able to help me.

**nginx.conf**

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /usr/local/var/log/nginx/nginx_error.log  warn;

events {
    worker_connections  256;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    wurfl_enable    on;
    wurfl_root /Library/WebServer/Documents/WURFL/;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }

    include servers/*;
}
```

**servers/bingo**

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name jock.bingo;

    root /Library/WebServer/Documents/superfreebingo.com;
    index index.php;

    access_log /usr/local/var/log/nginx/testaccess.log;
    error_log /usr/local/var/log/nginx/testerror.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param APP_ENV /Library/WebServer/Documents/WURFL;
        fastcgi_param wurfl_dir "/Library/WebServer/Documents/WURFL/";
        fastcgi_param wurfl_resource_dir "/Library/WebServer/Documents/WURFL/examples/";
    }
}
```

**My error message**

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'WURFL_Storage_Exception' with message
> 'The file storage directory is not writeable:
> /Library/WebServer/Documents/WURFL/examples/resources/storage/persistence/wurfl_1711'
> in /Library/WebServer/Documents/WURFL/WURFL/Storage/File.php:59 Stack
> trace: #0
> /Library/WebServer/Documents/WURFL/WURFL/Storage/File.php(47):
> WURFL_Storage_File->createRootDirIfNotExist() #1
> /Library/WebServer/Documents/WURFL/WURFL/Storage/File.php(39):
> WURFL_Storage_File->initialize(Array) #2
> /Library/WebServer/Documents/WURFL/WURFL/Storage/Factory.php(42):
> WURFL_Storage_File->__construct(Array) #3
> /Library/WebServer/Documents/WURFL/WURFL/WURFLManagerFactory.php(60):
> WURFL_Storage_Factory::create(Array) #4
> /Library/WebServer/Documents/superfreebingo.com/wp-device-redirect.php(46):
> WURFL_WURFLManagerFactory->__construct(Object(WURFL_Configuration_InMemoryConfig))
>
> ## 5 /Library/WebServer/Documents/superfreebingo.com/wp-subid.php(47): getDevice() #6
>
> /Library/WebServer/Documents/superfreebingo.com/index.php(19):
> require('/Libr in
> /Library/WebServer/Documents/WURFL/WURFL/Storage/File.php on line 59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one has answered yet, but I actually found the  solution and rather than deleting the question I thought I'd post what I did to solve it instead, for any future devs with this issue.

It was just a file permissions issue. I navigated into the WURFL directory to where it specified:

**/Library/WebServer/Documents/WURFL/examples/resources/storage/persistence**

Then ran a recursive file permissions edit:

**sudo chmod -R 666 wurfl_1711**

After that I reloaded the site and it gave the same error for a different folder, so I navigated to that one and did it again.

Hope this helps someone!